# How can I trigger an event ONLY when the user is tabbing backwards and NOT forward

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

In jQuery How can I trigger an event ONLY when the user is tabbing backwards and NOT forward.

```
$('.menu-item-has-children a').keydown(function (e) {
    if(e.which === 9 && (!e.shiftKey)){
        console.log('Tabin forward');
        $('.sub-menu li:last-child').focusout(function() {
          console.log('check it out');
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('hover');
    });
 }
    else if (e.which === 9 && e.shiftKey) {
      $(this).parent().removeClass('hover');
    console.log("back Tab removed");
   }
});
```

Here is the code I am using but it doesn't seem to work. The first if statement still triggers when back tabbing (shift tab).

The problem is when I hit shift tab to back tab the tab event triggers as well which is the problem.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doppel/X3cLb/)  Please Try the back tabbing. Notice it works ALL FOR when you backtab on the last LI in the submenu ... BECAUSE both events are triggering....

Comment: Could you set up a http://jsfiddle.net/ for us?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/doppel/X3cLb/#&togetherjs=baNez9yCuL

Comment: What do you mean by both events are triggering? No they are not.

Comment: I didn't notice you can't tab in jsfiddle... But BOTH EVENTS do trigger. I think the backtab triggers when back tabbing but once someone removes the shift key the tab forward events trigger

Comment: Put the visited tabs in array and compare the behavior of the user.

Comment: Is that the only way to fix this? I would really prefer not to do that. Because that is really dependent on the user

Comment: And when I track what the user does.. how does the fix the problem? Is there any absolute key press check?

Comment: Ventsi.slav is talking about hitting the browser back key. I too thought that when i first read it...

Comment: I do say back tabbing =  tab + shift. Is there a way I can make that clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you're binding the keydown events to specific elements and not the whole document as a whole?

I've simplified what you are trying to do and it works as a standalone piece of code:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if(e.which !== 9) return false;
    if(e.shiftKey){
        console.log('back Tab removed');
    }else{
        console.log("Tabin forward");
    }
});
```

What are you trying to achieve? It looks like you just want to open the sub menu on tabbing, in which case you can massively simplifiy your code: http://jsfiddle.net/X3cLb/4/